# exception for filling matrix in C#

Tags: c#, exception, matrix, input, try-catch

i have this code block below, when i'm filling matrix , if i put enter or space instead of numbers by mistake, program will stop, so i know that it needs to add some exception but i don't know where or how to add TryCatch in the code or what should i write in the body of TryCatch
this is the code:

```
int row = 0;
int col = 0;
int[ , ] matrix1;

row = Convert.ToInt16( Console.ReadLine( ) );
col = Convert.ToInt16( Console.ReadLine( ) );
matrix1 = new int[ row, col ];
Console.WriteLine( "enter the numbers" );
for ( int i = 0; i < row; i++ )
   {
     for ( int j = 0; j < col; j++ )
      {

       matrix1[ i, j ] = Convert.ToInt16( Console.ReadLine( ) );

      }
   }
```

Comment: You should just validate your input, and handle in some way that is appropriate (eg: replace with zero, or ask the user again). I don't see a need for a try-catch here.

Answer (score 0):

If you want only to display message and exit then you can use

```
int row = 0;
int col = 0;
int[ , ] matrix1;

int row = 0;
int col = 0;
int[ , ] matrix1;

row = Convert.ToInt16( Console.ReadLine( ) );
col = Convert.ToInt16( Console.ReadLine( ) );
matrix1 = new int[ row, col ];
Console.WriteLine( "enter the numbers" );
try
{

for ( int i = 0; i < row; i++ )
{
    for ( int j = 0; j < col; j++ )
    {

   matrix1[ i, j ] = Convert.ToInt16( Console.ReadLine( ) );

  }
}
 }
  catch(Exception e)
 {
  Console.WriteLine("You Have entered invalid character");


}
```